# Restassured Test Quarkus not running withing Docker Container

Tags: gitlab-ci, rest-assured, quarkus

I have a normal Quarkus Restassured Test working very fine locally on my workstation:

```java
    @Test
    public void testHelloEndpoint() {
        given()
          .when().get("/ifc")
          .then()
             .statusCode(200)
             .body(containsString("hello"));
    }
```

however, when I run this on Gitlab CI withing a docker container from image `image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11` it hangs. I suppose, the Tests wants to connect to locahost:8081 internally of the container, which does not work.
How to solve this?

gitlab-ci:

```
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11


variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s m2-settings.xml --batch-mode"
  #MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: ""
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    #- .m2/repository/
    #- target/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - java --version
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS install

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy
  only:
    - master
  when: manual
```

When I run the same docker image locally (not gitlab) I see the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 61.157 s <<< FAILURE! - in ch.siemens.bt.ifc.ResourceTest
[ERROR] testGenerateEndpoint  Time elapsed: 0.073 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

[ERROR] testTransformEndpoint  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.quarkus.test.common.RestAssuredURLManager

[ERROR] testHelloEndpoint  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.quarkus.test.common.RestAssuredURLManager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that using the image `quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:20.0.0-java11` works. I don't see why - because I am not doing native builds.